# Is $\{\}$ equal to $\{ \{\} \}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is $\emptyset$ equal to $\{\emptyset\}$? I know an emptyset contains no elements.  So I feel like they would be equal. Can someone explain how they wouldn't be?

Comment: The second set contains an element.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/65600/120540

Comment: Two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements. The former has no elements; the latter has $\varnothing$ as an element. Thus, they are different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No they are not equal. $\emptyset$ contains no elements while $\{\emptyset\}$ contains $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4):

$\varnothing$ is the same as $\{\}$.  It is a set with no members.

$\{\varnothing\}$, on the other hand, is a set with one member.

And $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ is a set with two members.

You can form an infinite sequence in which each term is $\{\varnothing, \cdots\cdots\}$, where "$\cdots\cdots$" is the previous term.  These are the finite von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: The last paragraph is not really true. The constuction happens to produce the von Neumann representations of $1$ and $2$, but in the next step it goes wrong -- it produces $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ rather than the correct $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ for $3$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive answer. To convince yourself that the two sets are not equal see what happens when you try to *prove* they are equal.

As usual to prove the two sets are equal you need to prove each of them contains each other.

One implication: $x \in \emptyset \implies x \in \{\emptyset\}$ is true vacuously.

But consider the other. If $x \in \{\emptyset\}$ then $x = \emptyset$. Now $x$ has a concrete presence. It is an entity. Therefore $x \in \emptyset$ is false.